# infinite while loop with | operator c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite

I'm going through Bjarne Stroustrup's Principle's and Practices using C++ and I'm stuck on one specific exercise. The exact question is:

> "Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (Each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered."

I thought the code below would work fine, but I keep getting a never ending loop.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int i1 = 0;
  int i2 = 0;

  while ((i1 != '|') || (i2 != '|')) {
    std::cout << "Enter some nums YO (enter | to exit)\n";
    std::cin >> i1 >> i2;
    std::cout << i1 << i2;
  }

}
```

Comment: You misunderstand what an `int` can hold.

Comment: @DrewDormann: An `int` can almost certainly hold `'|'`. I think you both misunderstand what `'|'` is. The problem is more subtle than that.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cin >> i1 >> i2;
```

Tells the program to read two integers, so the program looks in the stream for numbers. If you input '|', there is no number to be found and the stream is put into a failure state. The failure state [will need to be `clear`ed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) and the remainder of the [bad input `ignore`ed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) before more input can be accepted. But if you put in the numeric encoding for the character '|' (124 assuming ASCII encoding), the stream input and the conditional will both be satisfied, but now it's impossible to input the number 124 and mean 124 and not '|'.

Instead read in `std::string`s. If neither of the strings are "|", test that the strings really are integers (Probably by trying to convert them to [integers with `std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)). If you find "|", exit the loop.

MSalter's comment shook loose another solution that is much simpler than going to `string`s. If 2 numbers were read, print the numbers and ask for more. Otherwise, clear the error from reading a non-integer and read in a `char` to test for '|'. Here is a really simple and ugly cut:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    char ch = ' '; // can be anything but |
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter some nums YO (enter | to exit)\n";
        if (std::cin >> i1 >> i2) 
        { // we got nums, YO.
            std::cout << i1 << i2; // print the nums, YO
        }
        else
        { // not nums, YO. Let's see if we got a |
            std::cin.clear(); // clear the error
            std::cin >> ch; //read for a '|'
        }
    } while (ch != '|' && std::cin); // loop until | is read or cin can't read a char
}
```

It's ugly because input like "auoaioafksdjnfkm" will print out a prompt for each character and "klasdjfahs12938 2093854sjfljzlkfjzlk" will print out excessive prompts and a "129382093854" somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Note that for this particular assignment, there is no need to clear the error state: the program may terminate after `|`

Comment: @MSalters Agreed, and thinking about that lead to a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

`int` stores a number. `'|'` is a character, then use `char` to read/store it.

```
char i1;
char i2;
```

example:

```
int main() {

    char i1;
    char i2;

    while ((i1 != '|') || (i2 != '|')) {
        std::cout << "Enter some CHARACTERS (enter '|' to exit)\n";
        std::cin >> i1 >> i2;
        std::cout << i1 << i2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, won't work either. The assignment asks you to enter numbers, and this code won't accept 42.

Comment: He just edited the question by adding the assignment explanation .___.

Answer (score 0):

the loop keeps going on because you are making a comparison betwen an integer variable and a character value

```
while(i1!='|'||i2!='|)//does not work
```

because i1 and i2 can only posses values of numbers(0123456789) and not charactes(a,b,c,!,ª,|) i1 and i2 can never take the value '|' and the loop runs over and over.
one thing that should work:

```
    int main() {
  int i1 = 0;
  int i2 = 0;
  char c;//declare c
  while (c!='|') {//if the value of c is not equal to '|' run the loop
    cout << "Enter some 2 nums and a character YO (enter | to exit)\n";
    cin >> i1 >> i2 >> c;//give a value to i1,i2 & c
    cout << i1 << i2;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read a line of text from the console.  Exit if the line contains a `|`.  Otherwise, parse the line.

```
int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter some nums YO (enter | to exit)" << std::endl;
        std::string s;
        std::getline(cin, s);
        if (s.find('|') != s.npos)
        {
            break;
        }
        std::istringstream ss(s);
        int i1, i2;
        ss >> i1 >> i2;
        std::cout << i1 << ' ' << i2 << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```